# find day of year from date (and weekday)

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an application to find the day of year (1-366) of a specific date. I am doing this to compare dates and find the differences in time between them. However, I am currently having some problems... When I set the date to December 31, it says that is day 361 or 362 (depending if leap year) and if I set it to October 31st it says it is day 302 but if I set it to November 1st it says it is day 311.... I can't figure out where this error is coming from. Could you maybe point me in the right direction? And, how can I figure out which day of the week it is?

This is my class to find the day of year (doy):

```
public int finddoy(int month, int day, int year){
    int i = 0;
    int days=0;
    while(i<month) {
        if(month==1){days += 31;}
        if(month==2){days += 28;}
        if(month==3){days += 31;}
        if(month==4){days += 30;}
        if(month==5){days += 31;}
        if(month==6){days += 30;}
        if(month==7){days += 31;}
        if(month==8){days += 31;}
        if(month==9){days += 30;}
        if(month==10){days += 31;}
        if(month==11){days += 30;}
        if(month==12){days += 31;}
        i++;
    }
    if(year%4==0){ if(month>2){days+=1;} }
    return days + day;
}
```

I've just compared my program to a chart I found on the internet, and my dates are staggered... January, February and May are the only accurate months (in terms of total days)

Comment: Don't have a pc to test this but you might have a logic bug ... { if(month>=2)..

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I need to add the selected day to the previous dates.  I can't add 29+the date if the month selected is February. So it has to be greater than that. And it will only trigger if it's a leap year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int findday(int month, int day, int year){
    int i = 0;
    int days=0;
    while(i<month) {
        if(i==0){days += 31;}
        if(i==1){days += 28;}
        if(i==2){days += 31;}
        if(i==3){days += 30;}
        if(i==4){days += 31;}
        if(i==5){days += 30;}
        if(i==6){days += 31;}
        if(i==7){days += 31;}
        if(i==8){days += 30;}
        if(i==9){days += 31;}
        if(i==10){days += 30;}
        if(i==11){days += 31;}
        i++;
    }
    if(year%4==0){ if(month>2){days+=1;} }
    return days + day;
}
```

i think it works

Also be aware of the leap years: they are not every 4 years!

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the month starts at 0 in the iterator, and does not add days unless it is greater than one. If it is the first month (January) it does not add total days... So that logic is sound

Comment: Then why you compare `if(month==12)`?

Comment: It was pasted and edited from another segment in my code to find the max days in a month, but thank you I will change that 8)

Comment: Dude yes! Thank you! I can't believe I was iterating wrong :D Anyways, what do you mean leap years aren't every 4 years? Where do I find out more of this ?

Comment: A leap year comes every 4 years unless the year is divisable by 100 unless the year is divisable by 400. This means 1996 is leap because it is divisable by 4 and not by 100. But 1900 is not because it is divisable by 4 butt is also divisable by 100. But 2000 is a leap year because it is divisable by 400. Google it